# Update map marker upon state change in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, jsx

Am trying to update a marker position based on dynamic coordinates in the state of a another parent component ,the snippet below is all i could come up with , it renders correctly the first time but does not update the position , besides that obvious flaw , i think with the way my code i set up it would rerender the whole map if the marker coordinates where to change since its part of the mapview  , how can i go about this?

```js
<Marker
            coordinate={
              {latitude:this.props.route.params.bus.location[1],longitude:this.props.route.params.bus.location[0]}
            }
            title={"bus is here"}
          >
            <View>
              <Image
                source={require("./assets/bus.png")}
                style={{ zIndex: 5, width: 30, height: 30 }}
              />
            </View>
          </Marker>
```

Comment: where is your state change

Comment: my state change is in the parent component , my bad if i shoukd have included that also ,

Comment: i updating my parent state then the child component consumes the state from the props as in the code i provided

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`redraw`](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/marker.md#methods) after setState or to set `tracksViewChanges` to true?

Comment: no i did not do that , how would i go about that am a bit new to react and am just trying to prototype something out really fast haha